# OpenReadStream consumes too much memory and memory is not released afterwards

Tags: c#

I am trying upload a file (300 MB) via client application (BLazor) to a remote server. Here is the code:

```
    private async Task<bool> UploadFile(IReadOnlyCollection<IBrowserFile> imgFiles) {
        filesComponent.clearDragClass();
        foreach(var imgFile in imgFiles) {
            byte[] content = new byte[imgFile.Size];
            string fileName = imgFile.Name; 
            await imgFile.OpenReadStream(1000000000).ReadAsync(content); // limit is a little bit less than 1GB

            co.buffers.Add(content); // co object is a parameter that is used to communicate among components
            co.fileNames.Add(imgFile.Name);
        }
        // send file(s) to a server (MultipartFormDataContent)
        //return result
    }
```

**Problem**

My application normally consumes around 120 MB and when uploading a file (300MB) I was expecting around 420MB. However my applications consumes 1.6 GB of memory. While  debugging I noticed that line

```
await imgFile.OpenReadStream(1000000000).ReadAsync(content);
```

was responsible for consuming extra 1.2GB of memory.

Another problem is that extra memory that was consumed is not release even when uploading process is done.

**Calling garbage collector did not help**

```
System.GC.Collect();
```

Dotnet version : 6.0.101

Comment: Have you considered disposing of the stream when you're done with it? And do you really need to read the stream into memory if you're just adding it to a multipart request? Can you not just stream the data through by adding a `StreamContent` to the multipart content?

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama ```var s = imgFile.OpenReadStream(1000000000); await s.ReadAsync(content); s.Dispose();``` results in ```System.IO.IOException: Supplied file with size 299667554 bytes exceeds the maximum of 512000 bytes```. I have to stream data into buffer as a files can be send 2 times depending on the flow. First time server will analyze a file and send response depending on the content of a file. And if a user is satisfied with the result of analysis then he/she will save a file to a remote server.

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama ```var s = imgFile.OpenReadStream(maxAllowedSize: 1000000000);``` fixed the exception. However manually disposing did not release the memory.

Comment: Note that garbage collection has 3 generations. I'm not 100% sure of your process, but it seems like the method above then does not send the data anywhere. It might be better to save the data to a temporary file, etc.